# Arduino serial tx to Raspberry Pi serial rx

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I haven't found a useful answer to my problem from the many forums I've found. If you know one please comment a link below.

I have a Raspberry Pi Zero and an Arduino Fio w/ an Xbee module. I'm currently trying to do a simple test with the Zero and an Arduino Uno just to practice serial communication. I only need the Zero to receive data and not transmit, which is what several forums only direct towards. I want to take an integer from a compass heading (received by the Xbee from a beacon unit at some distance away).

So for my practice I send an integer on the Arduino using `Serial.write()`. On the Zero I simply use python and the library pyserial with the function `serial.readline()`. Also, yes, I've stepped the Arduino tx pin's voltage to 3.3 volts and I know the Zero is receiving a transmission. When I set the Arduino integer to say 39, the Zero will (with a print function) show the ASCII character corresponding to the hex value of 39 which is 9 (but it is a string not an integer).

In essence, my dilemma is I can't figure out how to convert the transmission to an integer that I can use trig with to make calculations. Firstly, I'm not sure if it's possible to make a fix on the Arduino side. Secondly, if it can be on the Zero, I'm not familiar enough with the pyserial library to know how to fix it. In addition to my second point, I've tried type casting it with `int(string)` to convert it to a string. I get an error code saying that the operation is invalid with an operator of base 10 (or something close to that).

I'm currently at my home and do not have access to my code on either the Arduino or Zero so please talk to me first instead of complaining 'show code'. I'm an experienced programmer and adept enough to talk through complications. Thank you.

Comment: it sends and recieves bytes ... you can decode a byte into its ordinal value with `ord('a')` for example to convert the string "123" into an int you just call `int("123")`  (this is in python... on the arduino side you would use something like `atoi`

Comment: atoi() or just subtract char '0'

Comment: so using ord() I can convert the character to the integer. Alright, after reading I want to check a scenario. Say the integer is a triple digit, ex.) 278, how would this work?